# Last element not added to array of a state element

Tags: reactjs, react-native, setstate

In the following code when first element (a) is passed to checkBoxClicked function, console.log(id) in line 2 prints a but console.log(this.state.dealIdToUnSave) prints [] where as it should be printing [a].

Later when an another element (lets say b) is passed to checkBoxClicked function, console.log(id) prints b but console.log(this.state.dealIdToUnSave) prints only [a] although it should be printing [a, b]

Any obvious reason this might be happening?

```
checkBoxClicked = (id) => {
        console.log(id);
        this.setState({
            dealIdToUnSave: [...this.state.dealIdToUnSave, id]
        });
        console.log(this.state.dealIdToUnSave);
    }
```

Comment: this.setState is async ,so it may not display the updated value on next code

Answer (score 1):

Since setState is async, you can log the state change in the callback function passed as second argument to the setState.

```js
checkBoxClicked = (id) => {
  console.log(id);
  this.setState({
    dealIdToUnSave: [...this.state.dealIdToUnSave, id]
  }, () => {
    console.log(this.state.dealIdToUnSave);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The state change may not happen immediately.It is mentioned clearly in the documentation of `this.setState` as

> Think of setState() as a request rather than an immediate command to update the component. For better perceived performance, React may delay it, and then update several components in a single pass. React does not guarantee that the state changes are applied immediately.

Comment: Is there a way I can use promise here instead of callback?

Comment: how can I do it?